# Self-promotion in comments

Tags: discussion, self-promotion

Is self-promotion in comments allowed or less frowned upon? The [FAQ on Self-Promotion](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#promotion) mentions answers, but doesn't say anything about comments. I've searched meta but it doesn't seem discussed, at least not in a separate question.

Comment: I think the law of commonsense needs to be applied - just because comments are not explicitly mentioned it doesn't mean they are not covered by the same policy.

Comment: Hm, I was thinking if comments are treated in any way differently with respect to promotion. For example, if I have reputation 111, so it might be not enough to warrant posting my open source project as an answer to a relevant question, then is posting a comment instead a good idea? (Question actually asks about existence of such product)

Comment: Typically that is fine provided there is disclosure and it isn't spammy and it adds value or is useful to the OP.

Answer (score 18):

Any such product or service promotion should be directly relevant to the OP's question.  Any comment that doesn't clarify the question, or ask for clarification, can be deleted at any time without warning.

Overtly spammy comments can be deleted on general principle.  In practice, spammers rarely bother to earn enough rep to post promotional material in comments anyway.

Comment: I have seen people spam their ad-supported blog posts across the site in comments on related questions. In fact, I just mod-messaged someone doing this after I cleaned up ~10 such comments they were dumping on highly-voted [android] questions yesterday. Also, we've had at least five people spam comments asking people to commit to Area 51 proposals within the last few months. While not commercial in nature, that's still pretty annoying.

Comment: @BradLarson I also witnessed one spammer who had many answers deleted for it start instead posting comments with the links.